# "No module named ..." error on Mac

Tags: python, module

I'm new in Python.
In my folder I have created python file "test_package.py". In that same folder I created a repertory called "package". In "package", I created a python file "fonctions.py" inside of which there's a function called "table". I'm trying to import this table function in test_package.py. That's why I wrote :

```
from package.functions import table
```

But.. when I launch the file test_package my terminal says "No module named package.fonctions"

I really don't understand, it seems i did every thing right.
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

To let python recognize the folder you have created as a module, you have to create an empty `__init__.py` file in the folder, alongside your `functions.py` file